Entanglement comedy with suitcases
It is very little I remember from this film but I'll do my best.
It was an American comedy. Likely from the early 1980s.
IIRC it was a typical entanglement comedy. Not sure if this was only a fragment of the film, or if it was a larger part of the plot, but there was two similar suitcases. Some (bad) men was trying to steal / get hold of one of the them. The chase ended up in some tall building, likely under construction. As a result some acrophobia tension. The two suitcases causes confusion etc. The suitcases typically slide out on some planks or similar up in the heights. Believe the suitcases were red.
I do not recall who the film was about, but it might have been a couple (man and woman) that was trying to escape the robbers/bandits.

This sounds a lot like Barbra Streisand's What's Up, Doc? from 1972. Little early for your time estimate, but right on the money for others.
From imdb.com:

Two researchers have come to San Francisco to compete for a research grant in Music. One seems a bit distracted, and that was before he meets her. A strange woman seems to have devoted her life to confusing and embarrassing him. At the same time a woman has her jewels stolen and a government whistle blower arrives with his stolen top secret papers. All, of course have the same style and color overnight bag.

Funny movie involving a lot of chases. Stars also Ryan O'Neal, Madeline Kahn, many more.

Ah, Madeline Kahn. Gone much too young.

Sounds promising. I'll have to get a hold of it and view it. I wasn't more then six or there around when I saw it.
